# SASS - Generate dynamic classes based on range and values

Tags: html, css, sass

It's my first time trying out SASS classes, lists and functions. I'm trying to create a function that will generate classes as:

```
.padding-top-1 {
  padding-top: 0.75rem;
}

.padding-top-2 {
  padding-top: 1.5rem;
}
```

I tried creating this generator function:

```
@function class($property, $start, $end, $val) {
  $classes: ();

  @for $i from $start through $end {
    $class-name: ".#{$property}-#{$i}";
    $class: (
      #{$property}: $i * $val
    );

    $classes: append($classes, $class-name: $class) !global;
  }

  @return $classes;
}
```

Invocating as:

```
$pt: class(padding-top, 1, 10, 0.75rem);
$pb: class(padding-bottom, 1, 10, 0.75rem);
```

Then looping over the lists as such:

```
@each $class-name, $class in $pt, $pb {
  #{$class-name} {
    @each $property, $value in $class {
      #{$property}: $value;
    }
  }
}
```

Expected output:

```
.padding-top-1 {
  padding-top: 0.75rem;
}

.padding-top-2 {
  padding-top: 1.5rem;
}
// Continue until padding-top-10
```

Error:

```
SassError: Missing argument $val.
$classes: append($classes, $class-name: $class) !global;
  │               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ invocation
function append($list, $val, $separator: auto) {
  │           ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ declaration
```

I am having a hard time debugging as to why it's saying I'm missing a `$val` property. Any suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `class` `@function`, it seems like you're trying to create a map with `$classes`, so you'd use the [`map.set()` function](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/map/#set) like:

```scss
@use "sass:map";
…
$classes: map.set($classes, $class-name, $class);
```

Furthermore, to iterate over `$pt` and `$pb`, you'd then use [`map.merge()`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/map/#merge), instead of creating an intermediary list:

```scss
@each $class-name, $class in map.merge($pt, $pb) {
```

Find the version with these changes in [this Sass Playground](https://sass-lang.com/playground/#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).